# Xero connection limit of 25 connections seems to Include Demo Companies

Tags: xero-api

I am connecting to Xero through their API with OAuth2. In the past I used to create Demo companies on Xero to test the application I was developing.

Every time the Demo company expired I created a new one and reconnected to Xero through the API. This worked for over 6 months of development.

Now Xero is telling me I have hit the 25 connections limit, but as far as I understood, Demo companies are not included in the connection count for the app limit. Where am I going wrong ?

I cannot delete any stored connections as they are live customers and I am not trying to add new customers. I am just trying to connect demo companies to Xero to continue development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one Xero demo company per Xero login record (which does not expire) and then there are trials which do expire.

The demo company does not count towards the limit.

While trials are active they will count towards the limit.

https://central.xero.com/s/article/Use-the-demo-company